Unhandled Runtime Error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'emit') socket.io
Before I begin, I want to mention that I am a beginner in programming as well as in using forums, so please be patient with me!
I have searched for a solution to my problem on this forum but I couldn't find one, so I'm showing my issue here, hoping it doesn't bother anyone.
Quick presentation of my project: I'm making an online chess game using Next.js.
To create communication between the two players, I'm using socket.io.
However, I'm encountering an error and I really don't understand where it's coming from (it might be something simple, but I remind you, I'm a beginner). Here's the error:
Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'emit')

Source
src\pages\home\jouer\partiel\index.js (121:11) @ emit

  119 |   let codepartie = localStorage.getItem("codepartie");
  120 |   setCodepartie(codepartie);
> 121 |   socket.emit("message", "4", codepartie)
      |         ^
  122 |   
  123 | }
  124 | 
Call Stack
handle
src\pages\home\jouer\partiel\index.js (747:12)

I have tried many ways to implement socket.io but still the same error.
Here are excerpts from my code (the parts related to socket.io):
Server.js :
const io = require("socket.io")(3000, {
    cors : {
        origin : "http://localhost:3001",
        methods : ["GET", "POST"],
    }})

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    console.log("A user connected")
    socket.on("message", (message, codepartie) => {
        console.log(message, codepartie)
        io.to(codepartie).emit("message", message)
    })
})


Package.json of the server: :
{
  "dependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^3.1.0",
    "socket.io": "^4.7.5"
  },
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": ""
}



Part of the UseEffect concerning socket.io on the client side :
    let codepartie = localStorage.getItem("codepartie");
    setCodepartie(codepartie);
    const socket = io("http://localhost:3000")
    socket.on('message', (message) =>{
      setInput(message)
    })
    setSocket(socket)


Function that sends a message (with the line causing the error (l-4)):
  const handle = () => {
    let codepartie = localStorage.getItem("codepartie");
    setCodepartie(codepartie);
    socket.emit("message", "4", codepartie)
  }


next.config.js :
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
}

module.exports = nextConfig


package.json :
{
  "name": "hess_echecs",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cookie": "^0.6.0",
    "express": "^4.18.3",
    "mysql2": "^3.6.5",
    "next": "14.0.4",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "socket.io": "^4.7.5",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.7.5",
    "ws": "^8.16.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.16",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.0.4",
    "postcss": "^8.4.32",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.0",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }
}

Don't hesitate to ask if you need any other resources, and really thank you in advance to those who will take the time to help me.
Gabriel
